# Loading and saving an image to Parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a web app where the user can upload images of something and then save it. When they save it grabs the images as File objects from the `<input>` and saves them to Parse. However, if they would like to edit this something, it retrieves the images' URLs from Parse and displays them in `<img>` tags. However, the issue is that when they edit some other information without uploading new images and then save, the save function sees the `<input>` as having no Files and thus saves an empty array of files over the existing images. If I could add the existing images to the `<input>` tag, that would be ideal, but HTML security prevents this.

I understand that I could simply have the save function detect that the person is editing or ignore if there are no images -- there are work arounds. But this issue manifests its symptoms elsewhere too.

I also allow the user to enter a URL to an image hosted online (it's actually a picker for the Noun Project API, but that's irrelevant as I am using a url anyways). When they enter this url, it displays it in an `<img>` tag. And when they go to save, the `<input>` is empty and thus saves nothing. So just having an exception in the save code won't help here -- as it won't save at all in the first place.

There isn't really much code to show for this, as it is more a generic issue than with something specifically in my code. I need to be able to save an image from a url in an `<img>` tag.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't like this answer but ultimately it is, as you say, a workaround.

In my app I used an MVC framework (there are many but AngularJS comes to mind as an example). So when the user hits SAVE, I don't check the  element but rather I check the model to see if there are any new or updated fields. Unfortunately for you the  will only contain files that were uploaded by the user and not ones that have all ready been uploaded.